# Dimensional analysis of power

Tags: dimensional-analysis, power

I am trying to do the dimensional analysis of power using two different ways

- Using $P = \frac{dW}{dt}$

$\frac{[W]}{[t]} = L^2\cdot T^{-3}\cdot M$

since $W$ is in joule

- Using the power formula $P = VI$

I get to $[P] = [V]\cdot I$ and $[P] = [L]\cdot [T]^{-1}\cdot I$ and I am stuck here, how can I get to the first result? $I$ is SI so I don't know what to do next...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the equation $P = V \cdot I$, the $V$ stands for *voltage*, not velocity. The units of voltage are joules/coulomb, and the units of $I$ (current) are coulombs/second, so you should get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is electric potential, not velocity. It's equal to $\frac{Work}{Charge}$. Charge is Current$\cdot$ Time ($I\cdot t$)